# Is .nonEmpty method an action or transformation in spark scala?

Tags: scala

Is `.nonEmpty` method an action or transformation in spark scala?

For ex:

```
val don = Seq("Hi", "Hello")
if (don.nonEmpty) {
     println("Not empty")
   }
```

Comment: This is plain scala code, not relate to spark at all. so neither it's action nor transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where `.nonEmpty` is used to filter a sequence, so it is a transformation, while the action is collect:

```
val rdd: RDD[Seq[String]] = sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(Seq("Hi", "Hello"), Seq()))
val NotEmptyRDD = rdd.filter(x => x.nonEmpty)
val notEmptyArray = NotEmptyRDD.collect()
for(element <- notEmptyArray)
  System.out.println(element)
```